# error in java class compile time

Tags: java

I am a working on the garbage collector part of java and I have written the below java class but it is showing the compile time error in eclipse editor itself on the method printGCStats() 
upon selecting it is showing the error "void" @expected , please advse how to overcome from this...

```
import java.lang.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;


class demoGrbage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        public void printGCStats() 
        {
            long totalGarbageCollections = 0;
            long garbageCollectionTime = 0;

            for(GarbageCollectorMXBean gc :
                    ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {

                long count = gc.getCollectionCount();

                if(count >= 0) {
                    totalGarbageCollections += count;
                }

                long time = gc.getCollectionTime();

                if(time >= 0) {
                    garbageCollectionTime += time;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Total Garbage Collections: "
                + totalGarbageCollections);
            System.out.println("Total Garbage Collection Time (ms): "
                + garbageCollectionTime);
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have define the method inside the method. It not allow in java.

Define `printGCStats` outside the main and call in main method.

Answer (score 0):

move the method `public void printGCStats()` out of main()

Answer (score 0):

You've written `printGCStats` within `main` method.

You should call it as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    printGCStats();
}

public void printGCStats() 
{
    /// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic error. How can you define a method inside another method?
You have defined printGCStats() inside main(), which is illegal.

Use this :

```
class demoGrbage {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    demoGrbage demo = new demoGrbage();
    demo.printGCStats();

}
public void printGCStats() 
{
    long totalGarbageCollections = 0;
    long garbageCollectionTime = 0;

    for(GarbageCollectorMXBean gc :
            ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {

        long count = gc.getCollectionCount();

        if(count >= 0) {
            totalGarbageCollections += count;
        }

        long time = gc.getCollectionTime();

        if(time >= 0) {
            garbageCollectionTime += time;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Total Garbage Collections: "
        + totalGarbageCollections);
    System.out.println("Total Garbage Collection Time (ms): "
        + garbageCollectionTime);
}
```

}